# Ideals and quotient rings.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $R=\{a+bi \space | \space a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \} $

Let I be the ideal $\langle 3+5i \rangle $

In the quotient ring $ R/I $

(a) Without finding zero divisors explain why $R/I$ cannot be an integral domain.

(b) Explain why $I$ is not prime.

In the first part of the question I found that the order of $(1+I)$ is $34$.
I was hoping that this would help me answer these two questions but I can't figure it out. I can know that they are equivalent statements as $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain. my problem is I can't seem to figure out how write out what an element in the quotient ring looks like. If I could show there was an element of a different order than $34$ I would be done.

Edit: i think we can use the fact that $(17+I)+(17+I) = (34+I)$ doesn't this imply that the order of $(17+I) =2$ ? But by theorem the only possible order was already proved to be 34 so R/I is not a FID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well note that for any element $x \in R/I$, $34\cdot x=0$.  If $R/I$ was an integral domain, then it's characteristic should have been a prime number, whereas $34$ isn't prime.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly. I am hoping it's ok now.

Comment: Yeah i thought of that but i wasn't sure if that only applied to the integers. but if o((R/I,+)) =34 then its isomorphic as a group to $\mathbb{Z_{34}} $ or $\mathbb{Z_{17}} \oplus \mathbb{Z_{2}} $  which by the categorization theorem both contain elements of order 17 and elements of order 2 so it cannot be a FID.

Comment: @Faust If you are allowed to isomorphism theorems then it's not hard to see that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle{3+5i\rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{34}$. Then your claim follows immediately

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

$\mathbb Z[i]$ has Krull dimension $1$. Therefore, a quotient by a nonzero prime ideal of $\mathbb Z[i]$ would leave you with a domain of Krull dimension $0$, which is a field. But clearly $2$ does not have any inverse in this ring, so it can't be a field.